# How do i make a custom HTML5 component in a slot inactive?

Tags: html, shadow-dom

I have a custom component that generates a list using a "prototype" element passed in via a slot, which then creates its' own content.
ie with template like

```
<template id="template-map-list">
    <slot name="element-prototype" hidden></slot>
</template>
```

and initial html like

```
<my-list list="foo bar baz">
    <my-element slot="element-prototype"></my-element>
</my-list>
```

"my-list" creates the equivalent of

```
<my-list list="foo bar baz">
    <my-element value="foo"></my-element>
    <my-element value="bar"></my-element>
    <my-element value="baz"></my-element>
</my-list>
```

which in turn "my-element" creates the equivalent of

```
<my-list list="foo bar baz">
    <my-element value="foo">My value is "foo"</my-element>
    <my-element value="bar">My value is "bar"</my-element>
    <my-element value="baz">My value is "baz"</my-element>
</my-list>
```

I have various ways of making the slotted element not display, but is there a way to make the slotted element (the element with `slot="element-prototype"`) *inactive*? (inactive meaning it doesn't call the "my-element" constructor and it doesn't try to create the "My value is 'X'" element content) In particular, is it possible to declare something on the `<slot>` tag to accomplish this?

obviously I could simply check whether the "value" attribute exists or similar inside the constructor, but I want to know if a declarative solution exists in HTML.

Things I have tried:

- added `hidden` to the `<slot>` tag; wasn't expected to work & didn't.
- added `style="display: none;"` to the `<slot>` tag; thought this might work since `display=none` elements aren't in the DOM, but it does not.
- use

  ```
  <my-list>
      <template slot="element-prototype">
          <my-element></my-element>
      </template>
  </my-list>
  ```

  This works for making the element inactive like desired, but A) isn't declared on the `<slot>` tag & so is dependent on the user of the element and B) moves `<my-element>` out of the light-DOM meaning any CSS styling on `<my-element>` elements outside the template no longer applies, which is obviously semantically incorrect as `<my-element>` is supplied the by user and ought to be available for styling to them.
- use

  ```
  <template id="template-map-list">
      <template>
          <slot name="element-prototype"></slot>
      </template>
  </template>
  ```

  Semantically this seems very close to what I want, except obviously it does not work because the slot is in the inner template & no longer slots content directly from the `<my-list>` element.